# Is it OK to add 'one' after the smallest? And what's the difference between adding 'one' or eliminating it?

Tags: expressions, pronouns

The sentence is :
The red laptop is the smallest among the three.

Comment: Yes, you can add 'one'.  Your original sentence is more elegant.  However, here is a sentence where I like to use 'one': *The red laptop is the smallest one.*